# How to copy files between sub-projects in Gradle

Tags: gradle

How can I make a sub-project copy a file that is produced by a sibling sub-project? All this with proper dependency management, and without assuming that any language-specific plugins (like the `JavaPlugin`) are used.

I have looked at the updated Gradle 6 draft [Sharing artifacts between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/nightly/userguide/modeling_features.html#cross-project-publications) but it does not really answer that question.

My multi-project structure is something like:

```
top/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  producer/
     build.gradle
     myFile_template.txt
  consumer/
     build.gradle
```

I want a `Copy`-task in `producer/build.gradle` to copy+transform `myFile_template.txt` into `$buildDir/target/myFile.txt` and another `Copy`-task in `consumer/build.gradle` should further copy+transform that `myFile.txt` to a `finalFile.txt`.

Presumably a proper solution would be able to use task `outputs.files` or some such so that `consumer/build.gradle` does not need to explicitly mention the location of `$buildDir/target/myFile.txt`.

(I'm completely new to Gradle).

Comment: It would be nice if you took the "suggestions" from the accepted answer...and then append your question with your "customized" code (that is the solution) that reflects the names (of objects/modules/etc)....you used in the original question.

Comment: I am no longer using Gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle gives you lots of freedom but I prefer that projects only "share" with each other by [Configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) and/or [Artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html#sec:publishing_custom_artifacts_to_maven). I feel that one project should never concern itself with another project's tasks and feel that the tasks are private to each project.

With this principle in mind you could do something like

```
project(':producer') {
   configurations {
      transformed 
   }
   task transformTemplate(type: Copy) {
       from 'src/main/template' 
       into "$buildDir/transformed" 
       filter(...) // transformation goes here 
   } 
   dependencies {
      // file collection derived from a task. 
      // Any task which uses this as a task input will depend on the transformTemplate task 
      transformed files(transformTemplate) 
   } 
} 
project(':consumer') {
   configurations {
      producerTransformed
   } 
   dependencies {
      producerTransformed project(path: ':producer', configuration: 'transformed') 
   } 
   task transformProducer(type:Copy) {
      from configurations.producerTransformed // this will create a task dependency 
      into ... 
      filter ... 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above (commented out the `filter` lines and put a path at the `into`, but `gradle tasks` says: "Project with path ':producer' could not be found in root project 'so_57774921'". Also, what about the distinction between consumable vs resolvable dependencies (`canBeConsumed`/`canBeResolved`) that the documentation emphasizes? Finally, I worry that `from configurations.producerTransformed` denotes the entire folder contents (e.g. things created by other tasks) and not just the things copied by the `transformTemplate` task, but I do not know. Finally, are artifacts not needed?

Comment: You'll need to configure producer and consumer as modules in a multi-module build. They'll need to be configured in settings.gradle. You add files to a configuration in the `dependencies {...} ` block. You'll notice I state the exact configuration which is being added so it will not include the whole project. Try it out and come back

Comment: Indeed, my `settings.gradle` was gone. Now it seems to work except that my worry about `from configurations.producerTransformed` seems warranted, i.e. it refers to the entire `:producer/build/transformed/` folder, not just the files produced by `transformTemplate`. So, if there are other files there, they too will be copied by `transformProducer`, which is undesirable.

Comment: Also, I do not understand the `dependencies` block: is `transformed` the configuration (with the same name) or could it use some other name, like `transformedDependency` while keeping `transformed` as the configuration name? Finally, is there any downside to your approach instead of the `artifacts {}`-based approach used in the documentation I linked (since your approach seems simpler)?

Comment: Yes, the first thing inside the `dependencies{...} ` block is the configuration you are adding the `FileCollection` to

Comment: You only really need artifacts if you are going to publish them (eg to nexus). You'd usually only do this if you want to use them in other projects which reside in a separate git repository to your multi module build

Comment: Each gradle task should have a separate output directory. If two tasks share the same output folder its highly likely Gradle's "up to date" checking will fail (net result is tasks will always fire instead of skipping when nothing has changed)